# Debian = aptitude how to deselect/disable automatic packages when installing software?

Tags: debian, aptitude

i want to install subversion. But I have already (manually) installed mysql. And it seems that aptitude will again try to intall mysql `mysql-common{a}`. How can I deselect the mysql installation when installing subversion?  What commands/paramters do I need to use? I used -P but it seems it is not the correct option?

```
aptitude -P install  subversion

Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
AbhÃ¤ngigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut
Lese Status-Informationen ein... Fertig
Lese erweiterte Statusinformationen
Initialisiere Paketstatus... Fertig
Lese Task-Beschreibungen... Fertig
Die folgenden NEUEN Pakete werden zusÃ¤tzlich installiert:
  libapr1{a} libaprutil1{a} libmysqlclient15off{a} libneon27-gnutls{a} libpq5{a} libserf-0-0{a} mysql-common{a}
  libsvn1{a}  subversion
```

Thank you very much!! Jens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you didn't use the package manager to install mysql, it has no idea that you have installed it.  The right thing to do is either use the package manager to install everything, or don't use the package manager.  The "best" thing you can do in this case is to [create and install a "dummy" package](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/ch-helpers.en.html) that lets the system know you have the appropriate libraries installed.  To do this, install `equivs` with `apt-get install equivs`.  Then, for each dummy package you'll need to create a file describing that package.  To do this start by running `equivs-control packagename`.  This will create a control file for you named packagename, which you will have to edit.  In this file, you'll need to set up your dummy package to provide the dependencies your other programs are looking for.  Based on the information from Arrowmaster, it would need to read something like

```
Section: misc
Priority: optional
Standards-Version: 3.0.1

Package: my-mysql
Provides: mysql-common, libmysqlclient15off
```

But as thelsdj said, if your mysql didn't install exactly that version of libmysqlclient, the program may not run.

Answer (score 1):

First when posting command output online, especially on a primarily english site it helps if the command output is in english too. This can easily be done by setting `LC_ALL=C` in the environment, for example just change the command to `LC_ALL=C aptitude -P install subversion`.

From following the dependencies of the subversion package in Debian Lenny, it depends on libsvn1, which depends on libaprutil1, which depends on libmysqlclient15off, which depends on mysql-common. So you can not install the subversion 1.5.1 package in Debian Lenny without installing mysql-common. Alternatively though you can use [lenny-backports](http://backports.debian.org) to install subversion 1.6.12 which does not end up depending on mysql-common.

Comment: thanks, that's a new learning with LC_ALL=C to change the language for me. It would be kind if you could also write the command, with which you were able to trace the dependency path. thanks!

Comment: I traced the dependency path manually using http://packages.debian.org/ because I use Debian Squeeze and have subversion installed without mysql-common. I remembered that older versions of svn depended on a mysql library so I had to find info specific to Debian Lenny.

Answer (score 0):

Depending where you manually installed mysql to, it should be safe to allow aptitude to install it again. The problem is that subversion is likely linked against a specific version of the mysqlclient libraries and if you don't install the ones provided by aptitude, it likely won't run.

Answer (score 0):

"apt-get --no-upgrade" might do the trick.  I'd try "apt-get --no-upgrade --dry-run" first to see.